# How to populate emacs completion collection when list items include spaces

Tags: list, emacs, mapping, completion

New to Emacs:
I am trying to populate a completion collection from a sql query:
All goes according to plan except the completion list is ends up as individual words rather than the complete list item as a string with spaces.

```
(defun test_sql_interactive2()

(interactive)

(setq look (emacsql db2 [:select [Accounts:acc_name]:from Accounts]))
 (setq var (completing-read
       "Complete an Account Name: "
       look
       nil t ))
 (insert var))
```

the variable look is the result of the sql query which returns:
`((Collective Retirement Account) (Stocks and Shares) (Current Account) (Savings Account))`

but the emacs `completing-read` function sees this as 8 words to use as the collection to complete from rather than 4 strings, so instead of `"Collective Retirement Account"` being offered as a completion, it is only `"Collective"`.

How can I have the completion return the entire string with spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Change the contents of the alist (value of `look`) that you pass to `completing-read` to be strings:

```lisp
(("Collective Retirement Account") 
 ("Stocks and Shares")
 ("Current Account")
 ("Savings Account"))
```

This does that:

```lisp
(let ((look  '((Collective Retirement Account)
               (Stocks and Shares)
               (Current Account)
               (Savings Account))))
  (mapcar (lambda (xx) (list (substring (format "%s" xx) 1 -1)))
          look))
```

Comment: Thank you mapcar and substring were the functions that I needed